# Create dynamic initialValue for String type field in Sanity

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

I have a document in Sanity. There are three fields- title (string), slug (slug) and path (string).

How can I use initialValue on the path field to show a custom dynamic string based on the slug value?

For example if value of slug is `my-new-path` how can I set the intialValue on the path field to `/blog/events/my-new-path` dynamically?

```
export default {
  name: "myPage",
  title: "My Page",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      type: "string",
      title: "Page Title",
      validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
    },
    {
      name: "slug",
      type: "slug",
      title: "Slug",
      options: {
        source: "title",
        maxLength: 200, // will be ignored if slugify is set
        slugify: (input) =>
          input
            .slice(0, 200)
            .toLowerCase()
            //Remove spaces
            .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
            //Remove special characters
            .replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'`’":*?<>{}]/g, ""),
      },
      validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
    },
    {
      name: "path",
      type: "string",
      title: "URL Path",
      readOnly: true,
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: So you are wanting to compute the value path after slug has been set?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes after slug has been set, we essentially want to append that slug to a "/foo/bar/" string to create a path. So that the value visible in the read-only path field is "/foo/bar/[value from slug field]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is use an async slugifier for your slug and use the client to patch the document when you generate the slug.

```js
import slugify from 'some-off-the-shelf-slugifier'

async function myAsyncSlugifier(input, schemaType, context) {
  const slug = slugify(input)
  const {document, getClient} = context
  const client = getClient({apiVersion: '2022-12-07'})
  try {
    const patch = await client
      .patch(document._id)
      .set({path: `/foo/bar/${slug}`})
      .commit()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
 
  
  return slug
}

//…
// schema field
{
  title: 'Slug',
  name: 'slug',
  type: 'slug',
  options: {
    source: 'title',
    slugify: myAsyncSlugifier
  }
}
```